# Как сделать этот код короче? пожалуйста помогите оптимизировать

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой HTML

```
<div class="vip__tabs">
     <button class="vip__tab active-tab" id="button-vip-mobile-agent">Мобильный агент</button>
     <button class="vip__tab" id="button-vip-zal">VIP-залы</button>
     <button class="vip__tab" id="button-vip-fast-track">Fast-track</button>
     <button class="vip__tab" id="button-vip-transfer">VIP-трансфер</button>
     <button class="vip__tab" id="button-vip-consierge-service">Консьерж сервис</button>
</div>

<div class="vip__info" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent"></div>
<div class="vip__info display-none" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent"></div>
<div class="vip__info display-none" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent"></div>
<div class="vip__info display-none" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent"></div>
<div class="vip__info display-none" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent"></div>
```

и вот такой JS

```
<script>
        // Секция ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ VIP УСЛУГИ

        //buttons VIP
        const buttonVipMobileAgent = document.getElementById('button-vip-mobile-agent');
        const buttonVipZal = document.getElementById('button-vip-zal');
        const buttonVipFastTrack = document.getElementById('button-vip-fast-track');
        const buttonVipTransfer = document.getElementById('button-vip-transfer');
        const buttonVipConsiergeService = document.getElementById('button-vip-consierge-service');
        //tabs VIP
        const tabVipMobileAgent = document.getElementById('tab-vip-mobile-agent');
        const tabVipZal = document.getElementById('tab-vip-zal');
        const tabVipFastTrack = document.getElementById('tab-vip-fast-track');
        const tabVipTransfer = document.getElementById('tab-vip-transfer');
        const tabVipConsiergeService = document.getElementById('tab-vip-consierge-service');

        buttonVipMobileAgent.onclick = function(){
            //убираем неактивный ТАБ
            tabVipZal.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipFastTrack.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipTransfer.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipConsiergeService.classList.add('display-none');
            //убираем неактивную КНОПКУ
            buttonVipZal.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipFastTrack.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipTransfer.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipConsiergeService.classList.remove('active-tab');

            //добавляем активные ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ
            tabVipMobileAgent.classList.remove('display-none');
            buttonVipMobileAgent.classList.add('active-tab');
        }

        buttonVipZal.onclick = function(){
             //убираем неактивный ТАБ
            tabVipMobileAgent.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipFastTrack.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipTransfer.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipConsiergeService.classList.add('display-none');
            //убираем неактивную КНОПКУ
            buttonVipMobileAgent.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipFastTrack.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipTransfer.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipConsiergeService.classList.remove('active-tab');

            //добавляем активные ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ
            tabVipZal.classList.remove('display-none');
            buttonVipZal.classList.add('active-tab');
        }

        buttonVipFastTrack.onclick = function(){
             //убираем неактивный ТАБ
            tabVipZal.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipMobileAgent.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipTransfer.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipConsiergeService.classList.add('display-none');
            //убираем неактивную КНОПКУ
            buttonVipZal.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipMobileAgent.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipTransfer.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipConsiergeService.classList.remove('active-tab');

            //добавляем активные ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ
            tabVipFastTrack.classList.remove('display-none');
            buttonVipFastTrack.classList.add('active-tab');
        }

        buttonVipTransfer.onclick = function(){
             //убираем неактивный ТАБ
            tabVipZal.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipFastTrack.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipMobileAgent.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipConsiergeService.classList.add('display-none');
            //убираем неактивную КНОПКУ
            buttonVipZal.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipFastTrack.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipMobileAgent.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipConsiergeService.classList.remove('active-tab');

            //добавляем активные ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ
            tabVipTransfer.classList.remove('display-none');
            buttonVipTransfer.classList.add('active-tab');
        }

        buttonVipConsiergeService.onclick = function(){
             //убираем неактивный ТАБ
            tabVipZal.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipFastTrack.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipTransfer.classList.add('display-none');
            tabVipMobileAgent.classList.add('display-none');
            //убираем неактивную КНОПКУ
            buttonVipZal.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipFastTrack.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipTransfer.classList.remove('active-tab');
            buttonVipMobileAgent.classList.remove('active-tab');

            //добавляем активные ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ
            tabVipConsiergeService.classList.remove('display-none');
            buttonVipConsiergeService.classList.add('active-tab');
        }
    </script>
```

Получается очень много кода, сначала при клике убираем у всех активный класс или добавляем неактивный класс, потом к нужному добавляем активный класс.

Пожалуйста подскажите как это оптимизировать?
я только учусь и буду благодарен развернутому ответу

Comment: связь прямая: возможность установки класса только одному элементу и снятию его с других. Пример там приведен в нескольких вариантах. Просто примени подходы к своей разметке

Comment: кстати в разметке несколько элементов с _id="tab-vip-mobile-agent"_ - это может привести к ошибкам

Comment: а что означает эта строчка: panelItem.__proto__.forEach = [].__proto__.forEach; из того примера

Comment: Это плохой пример :-D смотри другие. Вообще суть в том, что у коллекции которую возвращает `querySelectorAll` не во всех браузерах есть метод `forEach` который далее используется, и в этой строке `panelItem.__proto__.forEach = [].__proto__.forEach` конкретному объекту _одалживается_ одноименный метод из массива. Для более подробного пояснения стоит либо задать новый вопрос, либо поискать по словам _одалживание метода_